# LaTeX - Streamline PDF Reader Page Count

Tags: hyperref, pdf, page-numbering

My LaTeX document contains pages with different page number styles (no page numbers, Roman numerals, and Arabic numerals). The goal is to streamline the page count so that my PDF reader counts all the pages in Arabic numerals, from the first to the last, regardless of the different page number styles used and/or page numbers assigned to pages within the document.

To further clarify;

The PDF reader currently counts the pages in my document like this:

**(empty)**, **(empty)**, **i**, **ii**, **iii**, **1**, **2**, etc.

*Image:*

[image]

However, I want the PDF reader to count the pages in a logical manner like this:

**1**, **2**, **3**, **4**, **5**, **6**, **7**, etc.

*Image:*

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Do you use Adobe reader? It has a `use logical page numbers` feature

Comment: I don't know if this might help but the `memoir` class provides the `\thesheetsequence` macro which counts and prints the sheets (pages) from the start of the document. It is analagous to the `\thepage` macro but numbers continuously. There are also `lastsheet` and `lastpage` counters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), as this is not the default LaTeX behaviour. To have "plain" page numbers in your PDF document without refraining from using `hyperref` completely, load the package with the `pdfpagelabels=false` option:

```
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels=false]{hyperref}
```

Test document:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels=false]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter i\clearpage ii
\mainmatter 1\clearpage 2
\end{document}
```

As a personal note: please don't do this! Having to calculate the offset between the "real" and the "logical" page number when trying to jump to a specific page in the PDF document is extremely annoying, it is much easier if you can simply insert the actual page number where you want to go into the text box and your PDF reader automatically takes you there. Furthermore the real page number is displayed anyway in parenthesis behind the logical page number, at least by Adobe Acrobat (Reader), as can be seen in your first picture.

Comment: Thanks! I also agree with you that calculating the offset between the "real" and the "logical" page number might be annoying when trying to jump to a specific page, but since my document also contains the same page numbers several times (due to "\input" inserted appendix documents, each with their own separate page count), this seems to be the best approach as it still uniquely labels each page. Also, you couldn't jump to, let's say, all page 4s if there are several of them - typing in "4" in the text box would only find the first page 4, so the text box becomes irrelevant in this case anyways

Comment: @Anonymous If you really need multiple identical page numbers in your PDF, I suppose this approach makes sense. In that case, see the comment more as a general warning for future readers ;)